# Understanding copying objects

Tags: c++, copy

I wrote this:

```
#include <iostream>

struct A
{
    int a;
    int b;
    A() : a(10) { std::cout << "default ctor" << std::endl;}
    ~A(){ }
    A(const A&){ std::cout << "copy ctor" << std::endl; }
    A(const A&&){ std::cout << "move ctor" << std::endl; }
};

A init()
{
    A a;
    a.b = 20;
    return a;
}

int main()
{
    A a = init();
    std::cout << a.b << std::endl;
}
```

I expected that `A a = init()` imposes the move-contructor call, but the outpur is:

```
default ctor

20
```

[DEMO](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/62f2ddca6bdaee24)

Comment: `RVO` is compiler dependent - VS2012 in debug works as you would expect, but in release it behaves the same as your demo, so compiler decides inlining is better.

Answer (score 1):

The line

```
A a = init();
```

is inlined by `NRVO`. It creates an object by using it's default constructor in its segment of code:

```
A a;
```

Your move constructor will not be used here.

The move constructor here can be used with `-fno-elide-constructors` compiler flag. I've [modified your example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bbbbb89cf060a5b6) to compile it with this flag. But note, that default constructor will always be called because `NRVO` does not affect this in your code. `NRVO` only means that the object will be constructed in the storage that it is needed (not on the stack of your `init` method) so it would not be moved or copied. With the no-elide flag it can't be created there so it would be copied/moved there.